# Animated progress bar with css

Tags: html, css

I want the progress bar to go from 0% width to 50% width in 2 seconds. This is my code so far:

```
<style>  
  #progressbar {
      background-color: #000000;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 400px;
    }

    #progressbar div {
       background-color: #0063C6;
       height: 10px;
       border-radius: 5px;
       animation:loadbar 2s;
        -webkit-animation:loadbar 2s;
    }

    @keyframes loadbar {

    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 50%;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes loadbar {

    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 50%;
    }

}
</style>

<div id="progressbar">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

but when I open the page the width is 100% instead of 50%. what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loadbar animation was not closed. The animation should work now. I've also added a forwards keyword to only play the animation once.

```
#progressbar {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 400px;
}

#progressbar div {
  background-color: #0063C6;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation:loadbar 2s normal forwards ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation:loadbar 2s normal forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes loadbar {

  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loadbar {

  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/2Z7Qp/)

```
#progressbar div {
   background-color: #0063C6;
   width: 50%;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   animation:loadbar 2s;
   -webkit-animation:loadbar 2s;
}

@keyframes loadbar {

  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loadbar {

  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xMKCR/)

Set the initial width to 0%

```
#progressbar div {
   background-color: #0063C6;
   height: 10px;
   width:0%; /* ADD THIS <<< */
   border-radius: 5px;
   animation:loadbar 2s;
   -webkit-animation:loadbar 2s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Additionally, I added in the following..

```
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

If you want the animation to end in a forwards motion you need this... here is a demo demonstrating what would happen without it.. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xMKCR/1/)

Comment: Why `width:0%`? If you set the initial `width` value to `50%`, you won't need to add the `animation-fill-mode` property.

Comment: @Mori - I am setting `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so that I don't have to set the initial width to `50%`. Also, I wrote this four years ago.