# Jquery water flow through pipe Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a Single-Page Scrollable website for a Local Plumbing Company. I had a thought in mind which requires an effect like the one at :

http://sidigital.co/

Can anyone suggest me any JS/Jquery Plugin for this "Water flowing through pipe" Concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is mostly achieved using CSS3 more than a JavaScript effect. You could possible write a script that combines firing specific CSS events with a scrolled function, like the [parallax effect](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) and the effect as seen on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/2Z7Qp/).

The CSS Code cuz I am not able to [post the link as is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748121/393459):

CSS

```
#progressbar {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 400px;
}

#progressbar div {
    background-color: #0063C6;
    width: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    animation:loadbar 2s;
    -webkit-animation:loadbar 2s;
}

@keyframes loadbar {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 50%;
    }

}

@-webkit-keyframes loadbar {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="progressbar">
<div></div>
```

Comment: Well that's a good piece of knowledge. You have shown a good direction, rest I'll handle. I'll come back for more :D