# water flow effect through an SVG path

Tags: svg-animate

I have a task to develop a site which has a same effect as in the following site

http://sidigital.co/

i have gone through the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363237/jquery-water-flow-through-pipe-effect)
but my question is how do we implement it in tube like svg path